# Encapsulate Express Routers

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Is it possible to create different routers using Express.Router that don't share middleware?

To me it seems that Express.Router uses a singleton, so no matter what I try, the middleware gets attached to all routers. So, without having to create multiple instances of the Express app, is there a way to achieve the following:

**Create mutliple routers**

```
var router_a = Express.Router();
var router_b = Express.Router();
```

**Give each router unique routes and middleware**

```
router_a.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Only works on router_a!');
});
router_a.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('Only works on router_a!');
});

router_b.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Only works on router_b!');
});
router_b.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('Only works on router_b!');
});
```

**Attach each route to a custom url namespace**

```
app.use('/a', router_a);
app.use('/b', router_b);
```

Is there a straight forward way to achieve this? After reading through the docs on the Router I don't see anything that suggests such is possible.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many routers as you want and each are completely separate from the other and can work in their own subset of the URL namespace.  It is explained [here in the Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router).  In that specific example, `/birds/*` is handled by one router instance and you can repeat as many of those for other top level paths.  And, top-level routers can have sub-routers within them too.  Each router has its own middleware that only fires when the router's path is involved.

Comment: This does not seem to be working as you stated. When I set up multiple routers the middlware for unmatched routers still gets executed on all routes.

Comment: Can you perhaps post a working example? As I may be doing something incorrectly. @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I see missing from your code is the call the `next()` in your middleware.  If I add that to your code, it works perfectly fine for me.

The `/b` middleware is only called if the route starts with `/b` and same for the `/a` middleware with `/a` routes.  And, to finish your code, you also have to send a response in your `.get()` handlers.

Here's the specific code I just tested:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(80);

app.use(express.static('public'));

var router_a = express.Router();
var router_b = express.Router();

router_a.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('.use() - Only works on router_a!');
    next();
});
router_a.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('.get() - Only works on router_a!');
    res.send("router a, / route");
});

router_b.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('.use() - Only works on router_b!');
    next();
});
router_b.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('.get() - Only works on router_b!');
    res.send("router b, / route");
});

app.use('/a', router_a);
app.use('/b', router_b);
```

Comment: oh look, that works! Hm, I wonder why my implementation is not working? I have the router and app abstracted so i'm guessing I need to dig a bit deeper. I feel more sane knowing that it should work as I expect. Thank you.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to update my version of express. Thanks again for your help @jfriend00