# Exclude specified route from a middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this middleware that check every routes for user session. This just simply do if user logged in, go to next function.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/login');
     }else{
        res.locals.username = req.user.username;
        return next();
     }
});
```

But how to exclude it for certain route? For example I want to do a public API within my app also. Like example.com/api/items should not check for user login session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.originalUrl` tells you what the URL was so you can decide to skip your logic by examining the URL right in your middleware function.

Or, you could set up a separate router for the public path that was processed before this router so if the request matched the public path router, then it would already be handled and thus this middleware in a later router wouldn't be called.  That is how Express expects you to have different middleware for different top level paths - by using separate routers.

Comment: My app is half way, I don't want to go to the second options. But how `req.originalUrl` help in this case?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - What does "app is half way" mean?  For the separate router, you just put your public API routes into a new router.  It's the "right" way to design two paths with different middleware and should take only a few minutes of code reorganization.  My favorite coding quote: **"There's always enough time to do it over to make it work correctly, but never enough time to do it right the first time."**  In other words, take the time to do it right.

Comment: I see. Ok I got you. You're saying do `router.get('/api',function(){
//something
});` before the auth check middleware right?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - No.  I'm saying to create two separate routers, each with their own middleware and each targeted at a different portion of the path.  The public API will not contain the middleware that requires the login.  The other router will.

Comment: In my `app.js`, do this line `app.use('/api', require('./api'));`, and I have a folder call `api` which is my second router that don't run auth check middleware, am I doing it right?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - If your `./api` module exports a router, that is how you would hook it up.  Just make sure you hook it up before your other router or if your other router is on it's own separate path, then the order does not matter.

Comment: I got this error after doing that. `TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object`

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - Can't really help with that error without seeing the code around it.

Comment: I put `app.use('/api', require('./api'));` in my app.js, then I have a folder call `api` which has a `index.js`. I do the same for my first routes, but it's not ok for api route, any thought?

Comment: I've fixed the error, I can call my api route now, but it still go to the auth middleware, that's strange.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler - I don't know what  your overall code looks like, but this other answer contains an exact example for  how to use two separate routers on two separate paths, each with their own middleware: [Encapsulate Express Routers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931196/encapsulate-express-routers/35002834#35002834).  I've run that example from my answer there on my computer and it works.